# How to Run Parallel Appium Test With Selenium Grid Only By Specifying Platform

Tags: selenium, appium, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I am running parallel robot framework Appium tests using pabot. Below are my config files:

**configDevice1.json**

```
{
    "capabilities":[
      {
      "platformName": "Android",
      "platformVersion": "9.0",
      "browserName": "Android-Huawei-Matepad",
      "deviceName": "Huawei Matepad",
      "udid": "902xxxxxxx",
      "appActivity":"com.app.MainActivity",
      "appPackage":"com.app.preview",
      "noReset":false,
      "automationName":"uiautomator2",
      "groups":"device",
      "maxInstances": 1
      }
    ],
    "configuration":
      {
      "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub",
      "cleanUpCycle":2500,
      "timeout":30000,
      "maxSession": 1,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 1000,
      "hubPort": 4444,
      "hubHost": "localhost"
      }
  }
```

**configDevice2.json**

```
{
    "capabilities":[
      {
      "platformName": "Android",
      "platformVersion": "9.0",
      "browserName": "Android-Samsung",
      "deviceName": "Android Samsung",
      "udid": "111xxxxxxx",
      "appActivity":"com.app.MainActivity",
      "appPackage":"com.app.preview",
      "noReset":false,
      "automationName":"uiautomator2",
      "groups":"device",
      "maxInstances": 1
      }
    ],
    "configuration":
      {
      "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub",
      "cleanUpCycle":2500,
      "timeout":30000,
      "maxSession": 1,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 1000,
      "hubPort": 4444,
      "hubHost": "localhost"
      }
  }
```

I started the two Appium nodes in separate process:

```
appium --nodeconfig configDevice1.json  -p 4723 -bp 5723
```

```
appium --nodeconfig configDevice2.json  -p 4724 -bp 5724
```

The parallel test works fine if I define the `udid` on the desired capabilities. However, I am looking for a way to run parallel test without having to specify any `udid`. For instance, I want to run parallel tests on all devices with `platform` of `Android`.

When I run the parallel tests only with capabilities of `platformName=Android`, all tests run only on one device, conflicting each session from another.

I can see Appium is retrieving connected devices, but then only proceed selecting the first device from that list. This happens in both Appium sessions (Hence making tests failure because it tries to override an existing session)

```
[debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"111xxxxxxx","state":"device"},{"udid":"902xxxxxxx","state":"device"}]
[AndroidDriver] Using device: 111xxxxxxx
```

Is there anything one can do to make tests parallel on `platform` information available on Selenium grid nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. The config.json value set should be `platform` and `version`. It works well now!